# Pandas: Map value in loop to new dataframe based on column names

Tags: python, pandas

I have the following df:

```
A  B  C
1  3  2 
2  1  10
```

I now wrote a function that loops over each column to regress each column on C. The aim is to store the t-stat of the regression for each column in a separate dataframe mapped to the column name. The code is the following:

```
import pandas as pd
t_stats = pd.DataFrame(data = None, columns= df.columns)
x = df["C"]
for column in df: 
    y=df[column]
    results = fit_line(x,y) # fit line is a reg function defined somewhere else
    t_stats[column] = results[0]/results[1]
```

The problem is with the command:

```
 t_stats[column] = results[0]/results[1]
```

I want the t-statistic that I calculate out of the results tuple to be stored in the column named according to the column that is currently active in the for loop. However, the t-stat dataframe has the columns names from the df, but it is empty, i.e. the t-statistics are not saved at all in there. What am I doing wrong?

Desired output t_stat dataframe:

```
A                              B                                   C
value of regression A on C   value of regression B on C            value of regression C on C
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
t_stats = pd.DataFrame(data = None, columns= df.columns)
```

builds a DataFrame with three columns and *zero rows*.

```
t_stats[column] = results[0]/results[1]
```

fills every row in the `column` column with the scalar value `results[0]/results[1]`.
Since there are no rows, no data is added to `t_stats`.

So instead, collect the data into a dict, and after all the data is collected, convert the dict into a DataFrame:

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({'A':[1,2], 'B':[3,1], 'C':[2,10]})
data = dict()
x = df["C"]
for column in df: 
    y=df[column]
    # results = fit_line(x,y) # fit line is a reg function defined somewhere else
    results = [1,2]
    data[column] = results[0]/results[1]
t_stats = pd.DataFrame([data])
print(t_stats)
```

yields

```
     A    B    C
0  0.5  0.5  0.5
```

Note there are many formats for `data` which can be converted into a DataFrame.
Above, I used a list of dicts. Since there is only one row, the list contained only one dict. Alternatively, you could pass a dict of lists:

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({'A':[1,2], 'B':[3,1], 'C':[2,10]})
data = dict()
x = df["C"]
for column in df: 
    y=df[column]
    results = [1,2]
    data[column] = [results[0]/results[1]]  # <-- dict of lists
t_stats = pd.DataFrame(data)                # note, no more brackets around data
print(t_stats)
```

yields the same result.

Comment: thank you so much, works perfectly. But just for future reader. The second option yields a ValueError: If using all scalar values, you must pass an index. `t_stats = pd.DataFrame(data, index=[0])` corrects it.